Integration of signal
How can I solve this integral? I know this integral is equivalent to convolution with u(t). Hence the convolution of u(t) with u(t) is r(t) or ramp function. But what would be the convolution of u(cost) with u(t)?
N.B.Here u(t) means unit step function and r(t) means ramp function

The resulting integrand function is the product between a unipolar square wave of unit amplitude and period 6.28, and the unit step which is defined for t>0. Therefore the lower limit of integration is zero. So the required convolution integral should be the sum of the areas of each pulse (T/2) of the square wave up to time t.

If the integral starts at -infinity and the step function is unipolar, then the integral is infinite.

The unit step is zero for t < 0 so the integration starts from zero and not from -infinite.(Φ(x) is the unit step function).


what would be the expression of the result of convolution integral?

That sounds like a different question - not one for the comments. Would https://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better place for these questions?
